# JPA Named query join

Tags: java, jpa, join, named-query

I've got an issue with JPA, I need to return a list of users but I always get the user the id is from

This one is working correctly and returns the users that you are following:

```
@NamedQuery(name = "User.findByFollowing",
                        query = "select User from User user join user.followers f where f.id=:id"),
```

This query always returns the user of the id parameter (param=1 returns user1 instead of all the users you are followed by)

```
  @NamedQuery(name = "User.findFollower",
            query = "select User, f from User user join user.followers f where user.id=:id")
```

The table looks like this, both columns are id's of the user table.

As you can see:

- user4 got 2 followers
- user3 got 1 follower
- user 2 is following 2 users
- user 1 is following 1 user

[image: The table]

This is the user table

[image: User table]

The follower table is generated by JPA with a arraylist

```
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<User> followers = new ArrayList();
```

Now you've got some background info I will get to the point.

As user 2 I can see that i am following user3 and user 4. But if I am user 3 I can't see that user2 is following me (This always returns user3 in some way)

If you need more information feel free to ask

Comment: Why don't you do "select u from User u where u.id = :id" and access the folowers via u.getFollowers() in your java code? You don't explicit need the join if your entities have the relationship.

Comment: nice one! i was making it myself way harder then it should be. I tought this way i made clean code. It's late already...time for a good night of sleep and some thinking about this

Comment: I will put that as a answer so you can mark it as right is that helped you. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you do "select u from User u where u.id = :id" and access the followers via u.getFollowers() in your java code? You don't explicitly need the join if your entities have the relationship.